# Not able to upload/download files via FTP script

Tags: batch-file, download, upload, ftp

I have the following batch file which creates a FTP script to upload/download files from the server.

However I am running this with admin rights but the script is only uploading one file and downloading none any ideas?

```
@echo off

echo user a6954408 >>ftpcmd.dat
echo renu123 >>ftpcmd.dat 
ECHO cd /public_html/ >>ftpcmd.dat
echo bin >>ftpcmd.dat
lcd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp >>ftpcmd.dat
echo get Auto_Update.exe >>ftpcmd.dat
echo get Log.txt >>ftpcmd.dat
echo put C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Log.txt >>ftpcmd.dat

echo put C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Dev.txt >>ftpcmd.dat

echo quit >>ftpcmd.dat


ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat chatterz.net78.net 


goto :run1
:run1
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat chatterz.net78.net 


goto run1
```

**UPDATE : 19-06-2015 , 16:05**

Thanks for your help, but I am still not getting it..

```
Connected to chatterz.net78.net.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 12 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 06:32. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
ftp> user a6954408
331 User a6954408 OK. Password required

230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230-2 files used (0%) - authorized: 10000 files
230 6040 Kbytes used (0%) - authorized: 1536000 Kb
ftp> cd public_html
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html
ftp> bin
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
ftp> lcd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
Local directory now C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp.
ftp> get Auto_Update.exe
200 PORT command successful
550 Can't open Auto_Update.exe: No such file or directory
ftp> get Log.txt
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 53985
226 File successfully transferred
ftp> put Log.txt
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 53986
226 File successfully transferred
ftp> put Dev.txt
Dev.txt: File not found
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The files are still not being uploaded/downloaded any idea what can I do?

Comment: Had similar problem once. In my case the problem was that most public FTP servers require PASSIVE MODE. Check if your server does so. IF this is the case you could try to add `QUOTE PASV` to your code.

Comment: Show us output of the script.

Comment: Hello Michael , Thanks for your help I have added quote pasv to my code but it still does not seems to work ...  Can you try to give a example of it please so I could check if I have not done any mistake in it?.Thanks

Comment: `QUOTE PASV` cannot help. It switches the server to a passive mode, but the `ftp.exe` does not support the passive mode, so all breaks.

Comment: Hello Martin , Thanks for the help but my lightshot is not working so I have updated the program with the server link and the password , Please check the code above . Thanks

Comment: @AkshitSharma : Please accept an answer to actually mark your question as solved (and go to your profile to see your other questions and do the same) and remember to use up/down votes on the useful/useless posts!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generally correct.

There are two issues, none of which is probably the cause of your problems:

- `echo renu123 >>ftpcmd.dat` - You should not leave the space after the password as it is used as part of the password.
- `lcd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp >>ftpcmd.dat` - You are missing `echo` before the `lcd`.

---

When I run your code, it fails to download `Auto_Update.exe` as the file does not exist on the server:

```
ftp> get Auto_Update.exe
200 PORT command successful
550 Can't open Auto_Update.exe: No such file or directory
```

---

Both files are uploaded (if I have them on my local machine). So if they do not upload on your machine, it's because you do not have them in that path.

Based on your output log, the `Log.txt` was uploaded, but the `Dev.txt` was not, because it does not exist.

---

So I not think there anything to help you with. Just make sure the file you are downloading and uploading really exists.

Comment: maybe they are not found because of  the path? Maybe better use `%TEMP%` instead of hardcoded path.

Comment: @Stephan It's definitely nicer to use `%TEMP%`, but I would hope that the OP used a correct path.

Comment: well - he added his credentials. I doubt that his username is `user`. Maybe he missed to change it back to his actual username for testing..

Comment: Thanks guys for help but its still not working , Can any1 update the code and post here please? Thanks

Comment: The code is correct. It's the files that do not exist! What do you want us to help with? Do you believe they do exist?

Answer (score 0):

(should be a comment, but would be unreadable)

this is the directory of the given ftp-server:

```
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 59225
drwxr-x---    2 a6954408   a6954408         4096 Jun 19 04:37 .
drwx--x--x    3 a6954408   a6954408         4096 Jun 19 07:06 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 a6954408   a6954408           91 Jun 13 11:29 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--    1 a6954408   a6954408        53760 Jun 17 07:37 Chatterz.exe
-rw-r--r--    1 a6954408   a6954408           24 Jun 19 07:15 Dev.txt
-rw----r-x    1 a6954408   a6954408          226 Jun 19 07:39 Log.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 a6954408   a6954408            3 Jun 17 03:32 Test.txt
226-Options: -a -l
226 7 matches total
FTP: 497 Bytes empfangen in 0.06Sekunden 8.28KB/s
```

of course, downloading `Auto_Update.exe` will fail. It's simply not there.
That's what your log says:

```
550 Can't open Auto_Update.exe: No such file or directory
```